# How can get beans if spring context.xml load from web.xml?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/context/*-context.xml

        classpath:/context/database-context.xml
        classpath:/context/database-service-context.xml
        classpath:/context/business-process-management-service-context.xml

        classpath:/context/xml-sql-service-context.xml
        classpath:/context/ldap-service-context.xml
        classpath:/context/mail-service-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

I configured all the above beans in web.xml now 
I am confuse, how will get that all those beans.
Do I have to do this each time ...

```
WebApplicationContext ctx =   WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servlet.getServletCo ntext());
SomeBean1 someBean1 = (SomeBean1) ctx.getBean("someBean1");
SomeBean2 someBean2 = (SomeBean2) ctx.getBean("someBean2");
.................
```

or is there any other way ..... please help

Comment: There is that little thing called **Dependency Injection**.... You might want to read up on that.

Comment: thanks for reply!! actually I am new in spring. could you please explain is it necessary to get all bean in such a way...

Comment: As stated in my first comment read up on dependency injection...

Answer (score 0):

You can create new class that implements ApplicationContextAware like below:

```
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware{

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac)
            throws BeansException {
        context = ac;
    }
}
```

Now you don't need to load the context each time , for getting any bean just call

```
ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("beanName");
```